# Does a definite predicate logic have multiple ways to proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

This is my homework and the problem is to translate below into predicated logic and prove it with different methods:

> Determine if the following argument is a valid inference.“all the mammals are vertebrates;
>   Not all of the mammals are viviparous animals;
>   So, some vertebrates are not viviparous.”

My only solution is:

$P(x): x \text{ is a mammal}$

$Q(x): x \text{ is a vertebrate}$

$R(x): x \text{ is viviparous}$

Premises: $\forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)), \exists x (P(x) \wedge \sim R(x))$

Conclusion: $\exists x (Q(x) \wedge \sim R(x))$

$$
\begin{align}
&(1) \exists x (P(x) \land \sim R(x)) \tag{premise} \\
&(2)P(a) \land \sim R(a) \tag{ES} \\
&(3) \forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)) \tag{premise} \\
&(4)P(a) \Rightarrow Q(a) \tag{US} \\
&(5) P(a) \tag{simplification of (2)} \\
&(6) \sim R(a) \tag{simplification of (2)} \\
&(7)Q(a) \tag{modus ponens} \\
&(8)Q(a) \land \sim R(a) \tag{conjunction of (6), (7)} \\
&(9) \exists x (Q(x) \land \sim R(x)) \tag{EG}
\end{align}
$$

Is there any other way to give the proof? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The proof is fine; an alternative proof is by contradicition.

Comment: If there is one formal proof, then there are infinitely many formal proofs.  Or are you asking about different *methods*? i.e. something that is not a step-by-step formal proof? A truth-tree perhaps?